# Проблема с первоначальным запуском приложения iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

Нужна помощь в реализации приложения на платформе ios.

У меня есть разработанное приложение с базой данных, открывая приложение пользователь видит экран с двумя текстовыми полями(login & pass) и кнопка подтверждения.

Как сделать так чтобы при первом(после установки) запуске приложения пользователю выводило экран создания связки логин-пароль(администратор) и первоначальной настройки базы? 
Знаю что это можно как-то сделать через отдельный storyboard, не знаю как.

Comment: без обид, но мне кажется вам стоит потренироваться на отдельных проектах реализовывать данные вещи и потом приступить к данному. насколько я понимаю у вас опыта мало но вы взялись за готовый проект где нужно доделать функционал. поправьте если не прав.

Comment: Опыта мало - да. Но проект полностью мой. Это курсовая работа, решил делать то, чтомне интересно вместо того что предлагают в универе. А из-за того, что опыта нет тяжело объяснить что мне нужно и как я это представляю.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос очень общий.

Добавьте новый экран, сделайте проверку первого запуска приложения (например через переменную в NSUserDefaults), сделайте переход на новый экран и т.д.

Отдельный Storyboard тут не нужен, достаточно нового экрана.

Comment: А что на счёт Splash screen?

Comment: @GolovanovDmitriy Я не понял вопрос. Что со Splash screen?

Comment: Да, там советовали всякое. Попробую вашим способом, спасибо

Comment: @GolovanovDmitriy на сплеш скрине вы не сможете реализовать функционал. он появляется и потом пропадает просто и все.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно решить добавлением похожего кода в AppDelegate Вашего приложения:

```
 // Calculate root view controller
NSString *rootViewControllerId = nil;
if ([[UserService sharedInstance] isUserAuthorized]) {
    rootViewControllerId = @"revealViewController";
} else {
    rootViewControllerId = @"auth_vc";
}
self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                            bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:rootViewControllerId];
```

В примере можете заметить, что в зависимости от того, авторизован ли пользователь или нет, инстанциируется тот или иной View controller.

Comment: Попробую, спасибо!